# Flutter crash - Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, crash, crashlytics, flutter-ios

I am getting crash in flutter firebase database , here is the crash log on crashlytics

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException

```
0  CoreFoundation                 0x19f11098c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19ee390a4 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x19f1663f8 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1
3  CoreFoundation                 0x19f16f75c -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:].cold.5
4  CoreFoundation                 0x19effd5dc -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]
5  CoreFoundation                 0x19efef470 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:]
6  Runner                         0x104e69a44 __53-[FLTFirebaseDatabasePlugin handleMethodCall:result:]_block_invoke.437 + 292 (FLTFirebaseDatabasePlugin.m:292)
7  Runner                         0x104d469bc __39-[FRepo abortTransactionsAtNode:error:]_block_invoke + 1426 (FRepo.m:1426)
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x19eddd610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x19edde184 _dispatch_client_callout
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x19ed901d0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp
11 CoreFoundation                 0x19f08e3c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
12 CoreFoundation                 0x19f0893b8 __CFRunLoopRun
13 CoreFoundation                 0x19f0888bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific
14 GraphicsServices               0x1a8ef4328 GSEventRunModal
15 UIKitCore                      0x1a311e6d4 UIApplicationMain
16 Runner                         0x104cb0e58 main + 8 (AppDelegate.swift:8)
17 libdyld.dylib         

     0x19ef13460 start
```

Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
SIGABRT ABORT 0x000000019ef08ebc

Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception

```
0  Runner                         0x104cca6bc CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4329924284
1  Runner                         0x104ccaaa4 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4329925284
2  Runner                         0x104cba310 CLSHandler + 4329857808
3  Runner                         0x104cc8cb4 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 4329917620
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x19edde184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x19ed90c44 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
6  Runner                         0x104cc8720 CLSExceptionRecord + 4329916192
7  Runner                         0x104cc854c CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 4329915724
8  Runner                         0x104cc8140 CLSTerminateHandler() + 4329914688
9  libc++abi.dylib                0x19eede304 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x19eede29c std::terminate() + 44
11 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19ee392dc _objc_terminate() + 10
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x19edde198 _dispatch_client_callout + 36
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x19ed901d0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1044
14 CoreFoundation                 0x19f08e3c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
15 CoreFoundation                 0x19f0893b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2004
16 CoreFoundation                 0x19f0888bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
17 GraphicsServices               0x1a8ef4328 GSEventRunModal + 104
18 UIKitCore                      0x1a311e6d4 UIApplicationMain + 1936
19 Runner                         0x104cb0e58 main + 8 (AppDelegate.swift:8)
20 libdyld.dylib                  0x19ef13460 start + 4
```

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about why the exception 
 appears to be showing Crashlytics frames, it's known behavior and it's just an artifact of how Crashlytics attempts to write crash information during crash time. It doesn't indicate that Crashlytics itself is causing an issue. https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#crashlytics-frames-appearing-in-crashes